# Manipulate two list of objects in c#

Tags: c#

I have an objectA with an ID property and a Status property.
I have a ListA which is a collection of objectA.
I also have an objectB with an ID property and a Status property.
I have a ListB which is a collection of objectB.

I need to match listA collection with listB collection based on ID and if there is a match update the Status from ListB to ListA.

What is the best way to do this without foreach loop?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Create a custom ListComparer class which inherits from IEqualityComparer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ` for this:

```
var objectsForUpdate = (from a in listA
                        join b in listB
                          on a.Id equals b.Id
                        select new { a, b });
foreach (var obj in objectsForUpdate)
{
    obj.a.Status = obj.b.Status;
}
```

**Note** this cannot be achieved without using the `foreach` statement.

Comment: @No1_Melman How it can be done? he has to go over all the matcing elements. Could you please explain me how? Thanks

Comment: @No1_Melman In the anser you have provided, If I am correct you just check if there is any matchin element. You don't update the status of elements of listA that have a matchin element in listB. Right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel nope thanks! It does make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario. I had `cartProducts` and `productsPurchasePrices`.

I used linq to join the two collections:

```
//join currentCart...
var p = currentCart.Rows.Join(
        productsPurchasePrices,              //... with productsPurchasePrices
        row => row.ProductCode,              //first collection key
        purchasePrice => purchasePrice.Key,  //second collection key
        (row, purchasePrice) => new
        {
            productCode = row.ProductCode,
            productMargin = purchasePrice.ProductMargin
        });
```

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9